# Show value outside the ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show `{{Brand.BrandDetails.Text}}` only one time outside the `ng-repeat`.. how can i do this (repeat also want).

```
<li ng-repeat="Brand in Brands">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="~/Images/{{Brand.BrandDetails.Image}}" class="topBrandsBrandContentImage">
          <p class="darkGray fontsize13 fontWeightLight">{{Brand.BrandDetails.Presentage}}% {{Brand.BrandDetails.Text}}</p>
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: outside each `li` element? what are you trying to achieve? Post the expected HTML result

Comment: Where You want to show?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ Brands[0].BrandDetails.Text }}
<li ng-repeat="Brand in Brands">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="~/Images/{{Brand.BrandDetails.Image}}" class="topBrandsBrandContentImage">
          <p class="darkGray fontsize13 fontWeightLight">{{Brand.BrandDetails.Presentage}}% {{Brand.BrandDetails.Text}}</p>
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Mathew, I tried this. But it is not working. Therefor i used another scope in .ts file for first object in the list.

Comment: Can you present a jsfiddle.