# Get value outside ng-repeat angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have something like this (based from [Show value outside the ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494072/show-value-outside-the-ng-repeat)):

```
    {{ Brands[?].BrandDetails.Text }} // i want show element selected value
    <li ng-repeat="Brand in Brands">
          <a href="#">
           {{Brand.BrandDetails.Text}}
          </a>
    </li>
```

Actually it shows only first `BrandDetails.Text` but if i have 3 < li> attribute doesn't work. It shows always the first result instead the item i selected.. How can i solve?

edit: what i want is that when i click on the item of this kind of menu, it shows me the Brand.BrandDetails.Text of corrispondent item outside the ng-repeat.. So i can use the result from everywhere in my html

Comment: change `[0]` to something with ng-model attached value like `[selectedVariable]`

Comment: is it something to change only in html part or even in my javascript? have you got an example please?

Comment: What is your end result 3 different lists with the brands detail text on top? or do you want to loop through each brand and show the current in a li link? and how do you select your items?

Comment: see the edit, i explained well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in ng-repeat it's recommended to use ng-src instead of just src.

If you use src you will load `"~/Images/{{Brand.BrandDetails.Image}}"` as is.

I don't really undestand your question. What you want?

---

With this `{{ Brands[0].BrandDetails.Text }}` you're selecting the 1st brand.

With this `{{ Brands[1].BrandDetails.Text }}` you're selecting the 2nd brand.

etc...

---

or create a new `$scope.var = Brands[X]` and then call `{{var.BrandDetails.Text}}` or whatever

Please show us your expected output HTML

**UPDATE:**

Reference to your updated post. Use something like that:

```
{{ Brands[someVar].BrandDetails.Text }}
<li ng-repeat="Brand in Brands" ng-click="someVar = $index">
      <a href="#">
           {{Brand.BrandDetails.Text}}
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: and why not directly {{ Brands[$index].BrandDetails.Text }}? because in my < a> i have already an ng-click in which i have a get request.. Have i to create a variable inside this method?

Comment: because you are calling it outside the ng-repeat. so what `$index` mean outside the ng-repeat? maybe nothing. you can use `ng-click="something1; sometging2; ...; ..."`